# Declare multiple devices in a driver module

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I have to declare multiple devices inside the open call. Now is there a way I could fix the minor nos to 0,1,2,3 so that I can just extract that from filp->f_dentry->inode and put that in the array of struct scull_dev[] everytime I make an open read write or close call and then life becomes easy :P. Or is their a way to make life easier ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need, you shouldn't have ever to access your devices directly except for initialization and cleanup. Take a look at:

http://www.cs.uni.edu/~diesburg/courses/dd/code/scull/pipe.c

In `open` function, you can get the current device you need to open via:

```
struct scull_pipe *dev;
dev = container_of(inode->i_cdev, struct scull_pipe, cdev);
```

You can see in other functions how the device is accessed via arguments that kernel is passing to these functions. For example:

```
static ssize_t scull_p_write(struct file *filp, const char __user *buf, size_t count,
                loff_t *f_pos)
{
    struct scull_pipe *dev = filp->private_data;
```

Comment: Inside every file ops, the function *dev remains the same. i.e. the name of the struct scull_pipe. I am new at programming so pardon me if it sounds dumb but wont that just overwrite the previous declaration ?

Comment: No need to pardon :-). So, you're objects are living somewhere, in the global scope. They are at distinct memory locations and they are not interfering with each other. Now kernel calls `scull_p_write` and passes you inside `filep->private_data` pointer to some specific instance (it's like index). You do what you want to do and you change that specific instance. Next time it calls the same function, but now the pointer is pointing to some other instance, right? You can write to this instance, the previous instance will stay there untouched - as you don't have pointer to it.

Comment: I think I got it. We are just using *dev to access the memory allocated for the device in a particular way. Either way its just a pointer so reinitializing it to something again and again won't make a difference. Thanks again Sir :).